# How do I add global user specified autoconf module dirs for m4 files?

Tags: autoconf

In autoconf, how can I include more m4 files from a user-specified directory globally (that affects all autoconf projects)? Is there any way to set such a directory globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html), simply set the environmental variable `ACLOCAL_PATH`.